# POST Array data in ws with Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, api, typescript

My model object model.ts

```
 name_id: string[];  public generateUrlencodedParameters(token: string, id?: number): string {

        let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        urlSearchParams.append('name_id', this.name_id.toString()); }
```

component.ts

```
this.MyForm = new FormGroup({
      'name_id': this.fb.array([])
    });

  onAddItem() {
    (<FormArray>this.MyForm.controls['name_id']).push(new FormControl('', Validators.required));   }
```

component.html

```
 <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="name_id">
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let name of MyForm.get('name_id').controls; let name_id = index">
        <br>
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="{{name_id}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddItem ()">+</button>
    </div>   </div>
```

My problem is, when i post it to webservice, takes it in this format `name_id=FA163EBBBC1D%2C11E7FF6%2C11E7FF6FC1D`, so divide the array with `%2C`. I want to share with.

Can you help?

Comment: No idea what you're doing here because you're not showing everything you're doing. You using Reactive Form approach, but you never declare a form in your html. Either way, step 1, is it happening inside your component? can you debug and console.log() your name_id member of your form after you added first input entry?

Comment: No, declare a form in html: <form [formGroup]="MyForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddMyForm()" class="col s12" materialize> <div class="row">
   ...
</form>

Comment: send to your service myForm.value.name_id

Answer (score 0):

Create a proper form

```
  <div class="col">
    <form [formGroup]="MyForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="name_id" >
      <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let name of MyForm.get('name_id').controls; let name_id = index">
        <br>
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="{{name_id}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onAddItem ()">+</button>
    </div>
      <button class="btn primary-btn" type="submit">Submit </button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Use console log to debug what you're seeing inside your component
We can access a reactive FormArray by following syntax

```
(<FormArray>this.MyForm.controls['name_id'])).at( <index>)
```

or keep it simple by getting its control, and calling methods of that controller

```
  onSubmit() {
    let nameIdCtrl = <FormArray>this.MyForm.controls['name_id']);
    console.log(nameIdCtrl.at(0).value);
  }
```

Then when debugging make sure you can see the first input you want correctly

[image]

Comment: in console, show correctly. But when i look in fiddler TextView, this is with %C2. I don't understen why ?!

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in fiddler, you'll have to show it